# Pegar valor do atributo quando a página for carregada e ou select modificado

Tags: jquery

Tenho um `select`. Preciso pegar o valor do atributo `data-idconta` quando a página for carregada e tambem quando o select for trocado.

Estou tentando:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#formaEntrada').on('ready change', function() {
    var IDConta = $("#formaEntrada option:selected").attr('data-idconta');
    $("#contaBancaria").val(IDConta)
  });

});
```

Já tentei: ready, load, onload, live...

Mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa exibir o idconta assim que a página estiver pronta.
Você está somente configurado o evento, mas #formaEntrada nunca é inicializado. 
Veja um exemplo de como proceder:

```js
function getIDConta(){
 return $("#formaEntrada option:selected").attr('data-idconta');
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#formaEntrada').on('change', function() {
    $("#contaBancaria").val(getIDConta())
  });

  $("#contaBancaria").val(getIDConta())

});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="formaEntrada">Tipo de Entrada</label>
<select id="formaEntrada">
  <option data-idconta= "10000-0">Tipo de Entrada 1</option>
  <option data-idconta= "20000-0">Tipo de Entrada 2</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<label for='contaBancaria'>Conta Bancária</label>
<input type='text' id='contaBancaria' readonly />
```

O campo é inicializado depois que você configura o evento e não dentro dele.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de:

```
$('#formaEntrada').on('ready change', function() {
    var IDConta = $("#formaEntrada option:selected").attr('data-idconta');
    $("#contaBancaria").val(IDConta);
})
```

Utilize:

```
$('#formaEntrada').change(function() {
    var IDConta = $("#formaEntrada option:selected").attr('data-idconta');
    $("#contaBancaria").val(IDConta)
})
```

Comment: O evento `change` executará quando a página for carregada?

Answer (score 0):

Pegando carona na resposta do Fabiano Salles, com o JQuery você pode evocar um evento com o método [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
      //Configura o evento change
      $('#formaEntrada').on('change', function() {
        var IDConta = $("#formaEntrada option:selected").data('idconta');
        $("#contaBancaria").val(IDConta)
      });
      
      //evoca o evento configurado
      $('#formaEntrada').trigger('change');
    
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="formaEntrada">Tipo de Entrada</label>
<select id="formaEntrada">
  <option data-idconta= "10000-0">Bradesco</option>
  <option data-idconta= "20000-0">Santander</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<label for='contaBancaria'>Conta Bancária</label>
<input type='text' id='contaBancaria' readonly />
```